# Calculating descendants in a tree

Tags: java, tree

I've created a structure to represent a simple tree like this:

```
      A
     / \
    B   C
   / \  / \
  D  E  F  G
```

Each node is a Record which is my custom class with some fields inside. In the following example is simplified with just the field that contains the node's children. When the list is empty we have a leaf node.

*My goal is to write a function that returns ALL the descendants of a given node.*

This is the code I wrote:

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {

     HashMap<String, Record> treeMap = new HashMap<String, Record>();
     treeMap.put("A", new Record(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("B","C"))));
     treeMap.put("B", new Record(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("D", "E"))));
     treeMap.put("C", new Record(new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("F", "G"))));
     treeMap.put("D", new Record(new LinkedList<String>()));
     treeMap.put("E", new Record(new LinkedList<String>()));
     treeMap.put("F", new Record(new LinkedList<String>()));
     treeMap.put("G", new Record(new LinkedList<String>()));
     System.out.println(descendantsRN("A", treeMap));
}

public static LinkedList<String> descendantsRN(String rn, HashMap<String, Record> map)
{
    LinkedList<String> result = null;
    if(map.get(rn).getListOfChildren()!= null)
    {
        result = map.get(rn).getListOfChildren();
        LinkedList<String> children = map.get(rn).getListOfChildren();
        for (String child : children) {
            descendantsRN(child , map);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The **problem** is the following: when I print out the descendants in the example before, I only got B and C, instead of B,C,D,E,F,G. I do not understand why this is wrong. Where is the error and how can I solve that?

Comment: This is an awful lot of complexity for what should be relatively simple.  You haven't shown the source for `Record`, but I suspect it needs a lot of refactoring.

Comment: Record is not important. It has only 3 fields in total filled with strings. I avoided to make more readble the whole code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get only first-level descendents because you ignore the list returned by the recursive invocation of `descendantsRN`.

Calling `addAll` on result should fix this problem:

```
LinkedList<String> result = new LinkedList<String>();
LinkedList<String> children = map.get(rn).getListOfChildren();
result.addAll(children);
for (String child : children) {
    result.addAll(descendantsRN(child , map));
}
return result;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but I got the following error:  Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. Is this related with a wrong use of the LinkedList? Thank you.

Comment: @user840718 I see, you also need to clone the result. I'll edit shortly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your for loop. You recall the same function, witch gives a return statment. The problem ist that you do nothing with that return.
Try to join the result list with the result of the function recall.
I havent tested it, but i think it should work.

```
result.addAll(descendantsRN(child , map));
```